# Can't access GRUB after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, windows

I have a 120 GB Kingston SSD on a Compaq S21 laptop with Windows 10 Pro installed.
Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 21.10, choosing Advanced option during installation (not "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows") because I already had a 38 GB empty partition for it.
After installing Ubuntu, it started and ran perfectly but no GRUB menu was showing and I couldn't access Windows.

I went to BIOS settings and tried changing boot order, setting Windows Boot Manager first and Ubuntu as 2nd option and vice versa but no luck.

Right now, this is my Boot sequence in BIOS.

1. Ubuntu
2. Windows Boot Manager
3. 120 GB Kingston HDD
   ...

Now I'm running Windows because I have no option to choose Ubuntu when laptop boots.
Ran DISKPART on Windows and this is the result:

DISKPART> list partition

Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset

```
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System             100 MB  1024 KB <- /dev/sda1 (EFI)
  Partition 2    Reserved            16 MB   101 MB
  Partition 3    Primary            183 GB   117 MB <- Windows NTFS partition
  Partition 4    System             799 MB   184 GB
  Partition 6    Unknown             38 GB   184 GB <- /dev/sda6 Ubuntu EXT4 partition
  Partition 5    Recovery           518 MB   223 GB
```

Here is a snap from Windows Disk Manager

[partitions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9eWQ.png)

This is what I've tried so far:

-Installing GRUB to /dev/sda (main disk)

-Booting from Ubuntu USB Live CD and manually mounting /dev/sda6 partition in /mnt/EFI (doing chroot and mounting /proc /sys /dev/pts etc) and then running grub-install with no errors but didn't work.

-Running BCDEDIT with /set {bootmgr} option to set grubx86-64.efi (then deleted it to undo changes when it didn't work)

-Accessing laptop BIOS (Phoenix) (F10 key) which has a pre-bios menu with two tabs: "Boot" listing all boot options (Ubuntu, Windows, etc) and Setup. After you enter Setup then it finally shows you the BIOS config. Going then to Boot tab and enabling/disabling Fastboot/SecureBoot and CRM didn't work.

Right now laptop turns on and run directly to Windows 10. Tried pressing F10 at the very beginning and choosing Ubuntu from the BIOS' own Boot menu (GRUB doesn't show) but it always starts Windows.

Is there any way I can get access again to Ubuntu?

Sorry for my English.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are showing two ESPs  - efi system partitions? Most systems only support one per device/drive. After you change to one ESP run Boot-Repair. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair